# Websphere authentication session Expiry and redirect

Tags: session, authentication, jakarta-ee, web-applications, websphere

I have an enterprise application deployed on websphere 8.5.5.8, the application web side is composed of a single main page with multiple functionality tabs and every thing inside them uses ajax and iframes. Now, the issue is that I need to redirect the user to the login page immediately when the session expires. I tried to send ajax requests every second from my main page to the server to check for the session validity but the server treats that ajax requests url as secured resource causing the session to be refreshed and never expires. What are the possible work arounds for such scenario?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, call to server will extend the session. As one of the solution, you could use javascript `setTimeout` method, initialize it to the session expiration time, and reset on your ajax business calls. If user will not do anything, then this timeout will invoke call to the logout page, which will invalidate the session and logout user.

Comment: I already do this by sending ajax calls on periods equal to the session max time to live minus few seconds  and calculate the time manually to logout and this works fine.But there are differnt scenarios not handled in this case. One case I have if the user tried to open the application in different browser or tab I invalidate the session immediately, and so I need immediate redirect for the opened application tabs or windows.